# Proper "Grommet" For PoE Cabling Into Attic From Exterior?

Tags: security, soffit

[image]

I'm going to be installing a number of security cameras around the house exterior.  The plan is to run the ethernet cabling for them through these holes, through the attic, and down into the room with the network cabinet.

1. There are existing screens installed from the inside on these and I would have to cut them out to fit the ethernet cables. But I don't think I could ever get to them from the inside to replace them, so I do NOT want to mess this up.  I have a fish tape, plan to get on a ladder from the exterior, cut out the screen, fish the ethernet cables through from the outside well into the inside, then get into the attic and climb around like a rat to get to them from there.   Is there a better way?  Drill a specific hole? Yikes, I hate the idea of putting holes in a house, but am looking the the "he did it the right way" way...
2. Are there grommets that would be good to use to replace the screens that will allow a bundle of Cat5/6 style cable to go through, but still keep out the birds and the bees (LOL)?

Comment: that is not a summer job, you will get heat stroke in the attic

Comment: you don't really want to clog your soffit intake vents with cables.  Cables are really hard to seal around especially multiple cables.  I recommend drilling multiple 1/2" holes.  One for each ethernet cable then you can seal around them with duct putty - something like Gardner Bender Duct Seal - 1Lb Pugs.

Comment: Those holes and screens serve an important purpose. Odds are excellent that there are not a great many more of them than your roof venting requires. Therefore, closing off a number of them to serve as cable passages is ... **not** "doing it the right way" - **drill new holes that don't block your vents!!!**

Comment: Depending on how thick the wall is, you could consider a cable gland.

Comment: Okay great thanks for the input; that's why I'm asking.  I'm going to have a lot of these; cameras and PoE lighting; 10-15 range.  So individual holes for each wouldn't be good.  I'll start searching on the term "cable gland."  Sometimes just knowing the search term is enough :)

Comment: Why do you think that "individual holes for each wouldn't be good"? So long as each hole is neatly made and sealed (reference "duct putty", above), you'll be just fine.

Comment: Could you just run one cable through the wall, and use a PoE switch on the outside to the cameras?

Comment: A PoE switch on the outside is a very interesting idea....

Comment: Ahh, here are the search words finding all kinds of options:  "exterior cable pass through, cable clam, cable gland, ventilator cover clam shell."  And there are marine type options that look interesting....